# How not to re-use existing connection on curl_easy_perform(), hangs on internet connection change

Tags: c++, libcurl

With verbose, I noticed the outputs:

By the end of first run:

```
* Connection #0 to host www.example.com left intact
```

At beginning of the second run:

```
* Found bundle for host www.example.com: 0x24e3360 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host www.example.com
```

I want a way to ***not*** re-use the existing connection, or verify before using the existing connection.

### Additional Details:

I'm performing some simple web-page download using the libCurl 'easy' interface. I have a class that inits and sets a few options in it's constructor. In a perform method, I add the url option and then do curl_easy_perform(...).

Trying to do operation using my class, I have noticed:

- If first operation was offline, next operations act as if offline (even when online)
- If first operation was online, and then the internet connection was turned off, in the next operation, the curl_easy_perform(...) hangs and never returns.

I want a more appropriate behavior and operation based on current internet connection. (I have tried clean up and re-init + option setting in perform method, which works, but that seems a little wasteful.)

Comment: As a guess, this is a price of using 'easy' methods; you do not have to handle error cases, but then the error cases are handled in a way you do not want them to be.  Have you considered using non-'easy' methods to solve your problem?  If so, what went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went with:

`curl_easy_setopt(myEasy_handle, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);`

Which I added in the constructor of my class for one time setup. This will likely slow down the operation, but it seems to do the job and possibly faster than cleanup and re-inits or, using another separate connection to some server for internet connection checks.

I used it as it seemed more fitting than other options for my program. Two of the useful link I looked at for this are following: [link1](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2008-04/0463.html), [link2](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2010-10/0156.html).

**Edit:**

I also added the option `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` to set a hard limit on how long to wait before stopping if - during a easy_perform, internet connection goes down.